# SQL Count column value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SSMS 2016 in DBO [Warehouse_DB].[dbo].[WorkItemHistory]:
I am trying to Count the times in a historical record column (Owner_ID) it changes from a value not in my group to a value in my group. My Group being **SAG** or any username containing **Promtera**.

In the Below case (ordered chronologically oldest to newest starting with Joe Schomoe) it would count **3**. 1. the first SAG, 2. Alex (Promtera), 3. the second SAG.
Bill (Promtera) wouldn't count because the previous value was SAG and so already a part of my group.

```
TimeStamp     Owner_ID 
1:45 AM      Joe Schmoe  
2:45 AM      SAG  
3:36 AM      Bill (Promtera)  
7:15 AM      Bill (Promtera)  
8:56 AM      SOR  
11:30 AM     Sal Smith  
12:45 PM     Alex (Promtera)  
1:45 PM      SOR  
4:45 PM      SAG`
```

Comment: I don't follow your logic, but immediately I see a problem here because you never specified which column is being used to determine what is "first" or "second."  For all intents and purposes, SQL tables are unordered; if you conceive of an order, you must have a column which provides it.

Comment: (1) You need a column to specify the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  (2) Tag with a database -- which is presumably SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Edited to address comments

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you are using SQL Server 2016 you can use `LAG()` to get the value of the previous row and the compare against the current row:

```
CREATE TABLE Log ([TimeStamp] time, [Owner_ID] varchar(15)) ;

INSERT INTO Log
    ([TimeStamp], [Owner_ID])
VALUES
    ('1:45 AM', 'Joe Schmoe'),
    ('2:45 AM', 'SAG'),
    ('3:36 AM', 'Bill (Promtera)'),
    ('7:15 AM', 'Bill (Promtera)'),
    ('8:56 AM', 'SOR'),
    ('11:30 AM', 'Sal Smith'),
    ('12:45 PM', 'Alex (Promtera)'),
    ('1:45 PM', 'SOR'),
    ('4:45 PM', 'SAG');

with ProcesedLog as (
select Owner_ID,
  lag(Owner_ID,1,Owner_ID) over(order by [TimeStamp]) as PreviousID
from Log
)
select sum(case when MyGroup!=PreviousMyGroup and MyGroup=1
                then 1 else 0 end) as ChangesToMyGrpup
from (select
    case when Owner_ID='SAG' or Owner_ID like '%(Promtera)%'
         then 1 else 0 end as MyGroup,
    case when PreviousID='SAG' or PreviousID like '%(Promtera)%'
         then 1 else 0 end as PreviousMyGroup
  from ProcesedLog)
as MyGroups
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3689/1)